# Apache 2.4 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I have a website that requires PHP 5.4 and in order to use that version I needed to add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php` to my .htaccess file and everything works on my web server.

On my local computer when I view a page it displays the source as text instead of running it as PHP.

If I comment out the line in .htaccess everything works fine.

I noticed my httpd.conf file has `AddHandler fcgid-script .php` and the .htaccess file is overwriting it and it doesn't know what the handler application/x-httpd-php54 is.

How do I tell my local computer the application/x-httpd-php54 is the same thing as fcgid-script so I don't have to worry about uncommenting and recommenting the line in .htaccess everytime I upload it to the server?

Comment: shouldn't it be `AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php`

Comment: nope it's `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php`